# Does anyone from Team Iron Man wear caps?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, captain-america-civil-war, clothing

I saw this picture showing a bunch of Team Cap wearing caps.
[image]

I'm wondering how accurate this is. Does anyone from Team Iron Man also wear caps?

Comment: Ironically, you can tell from [their neat](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/08/09/16/2B37D30900000578-0-image-m-31_1439133175401.jpg) [appearance](http://data.techtimes.com/data/images/full/124371/civil-war-germany-set-pic-jpg.jpg) that everything worn by Team Cap is meticulously *ironed*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, Tony Stark himself wears a cap in *Iron Man 3*.

[image: Tony Stark in a cap.]

Unsurprisingly, he's in disguise at the time. He does also wear a hoodie, though, making him one of the best hiders in the entire MCU.

Comment: Spiderman wears a cap, a hoodie AND and mask.